# Adding shine effect to a table row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a shine effect to a table row following this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqQc7/511/

```
.gold:after {
  animation: shine 1.5s infinite linear alternate;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -110%;
  left: -210%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg);

  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 77%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 92%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
  );
}

.gold:active:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes shine{
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -30%;
    left: -30%;
    transition-property: left, top, opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.7s, 0.7s, 0.15s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
}
```

But I can't seem to get it right, the effect is overflowing the table: https://jsfiddle.net/uokvjaxx/2/

I added the class to just one table row and the effect goes through the whole table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gold">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to limit the effect to just the table row without affecting how the row displays?

Comment: Two initial suggestions: Heavy styling of table elements can be problematic. Instead, put structural markup inside the table cells and style that. Then, absolutely positioned elements must be contained by another element that's positioned other than static. You can see that demonstrated in the first fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this will get you closer to where you want. Customize as you need and don't forget vendor prefixes if you need to support different browsers.

```css
.gold {
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff087, #eccf02, #fff087);
 background-size: 50% 100%;
 animation: linear-gradient 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes linear-gradient {
 0% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }

 100% {
  background-position: 400% 400%
 }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th> 
  <th>Age</th>
 </tr>
 <tr class="gold">
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td>50</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td> 
  <td>94</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's a better and simple solution.